# WebView next/previous page transitions

Tags: android, webview

I'm generating a book app, of sorts, that displays pages in a `WebView`. I have Next/Previous `ImageButtons` and a `GestureOverlay` to detect left/right swipes. 
When I want a page change I call:

```
private void changePage(int delta) {
    currentPageIndex = currentPageIndex + delta;        
    if (currentPageIndex < 0) {
        // negative index
        currentPageIndex = 0;
    } else if (currentPageIndex >= listOfPages.length) {
        // index requested is out of range of the list
        currentPageIndex = listOfPages.length - 1;
    } else {
        // set values for page load
        filename = listOfPages[currentPageIndex];
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + filename);
    }
}
```

'listOfPages' is a string array of my filenames and loadUrl() works great, but is there any way that anyone knows of to be able to have a page transition to simulate a simple page turn?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I found a way to do this. 
I defined `Animation` variables:

```
Animation slideLeftAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.slide_left);
Animation slideRightAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.slide_right);
```

And the `slide_left` and `slide_right` xml files are from the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) tutorials.

Then, for left or right swipes, I used `mWebView.startAnimation(leftOrRightAnimation);` before my `mWebView.loadUrl(url);` call. 
Hope this helps anyone else! 
Chris

Comment: Awesome! It would have taken me hours to figure this out.