# Android app overridePendingTransition not shown

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app with the `Main Activity` using `WebView` to load a webpage.

I am trying to set animation when the user wants to go back to the previous webpage using the back button on the device (not a back button on the screen) but the animation is not shown at all.

The code below is outside of `onCreate()`.

NOTE: Notice that i tried `overridePendingTransition` in each line i commented out with no any effect.

Here is the Code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("BACK", " Back pressed!");
      //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
          //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
      //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
     //finish();
        return;
    }
```

If I use `finish()` it exits the app instead of going back.

Here the slide_in_right xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />

    <alpha android:duration="500" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

And finally the slide_out_left:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="500" />

    <alpha android:duration="500" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

I am not sure what i am missing. I have already checked a lot of the topics but i couldn't fix mine issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any  previous `Activity` in stack when you finish?

Comment: @KishoreJethava no there is no other `Activity`. The current activity is the Main Activity which is has a `WebView` that loads a webpage. So when the user clicks the back button of the device I want to have the animations above. Is it possible?

Comment: means you want to close `WebView` only with animation? in my answer it will close app with animation

Comment: @KishoreJethava No, i want to go back to the previous webpage with animation, not close the app with animation.

Comment: your question is misleading

Comment: @KishoreJethava you are right. I edited my question.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520337/webview-next-previous-page-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `super.onBackPressed();` from `public void onBackPressed()` because it will give a super call and activity gets finished there only.

Change your onBackPressed() code to :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
```

Yes, as mentioned by Kishore Jethava. You should call finish() first and then onerridingPendingTransition(..)

Comment: i already tried this but it ends the app instead of going back.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution!!!

call **overridePendingTransition** after finishing `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_backin, R.anim.activity_back_out);

}
```

**activity_backin.xml** in `anim` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**activity_back_out.xml** in `anim` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
</set>
```